# How to use apply in R with two data frames?

Tags: r, apply, stop-words

**Background**

I have a dataframe with ~1M rows of text. I want to replace a large list of custom stopwords, which the TM package cannot handle. The list consists of ~37K words. I have the following code that works and it takes a while, but I want to improve the code with an apply function.

**Problem**

I don't know how to use content from two dataframes in the applicable apply function. Here is my code:

```
stopwords <- read.table("stopwords.csv", header=TRUE, quote="\"", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
corpus <- read.delim("corpus.txt", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for(i in 1:nrow(stopwords)){
  corpus$text <- gsub(paste("\\<",stopwords$list[i],"\\>", sep=""), "", corpus$text)
  message(paste(i, stopwords$list[i], sep=" - ")) #Show in console
}
```

I also display the current count/word in the console to track progress, but once I have an apply function working, I will wrap it in the pbapply package to get a proper progress bar.

**Sample Data**

*Corpus Dataframe* - Single column with "text" as header
police worlds acted decisively premier mike baird
police operation map affected traffic area live traffic nsw
commissioner scipione number hostages undisclosed
nsw premier manner avoid martin place aware vigilant
happening thoughts heart hostages families affected
lindt cafe nice brave mighty warrior allah ikea dickhead
police advising citizens business avoid marketplaces

*Stopwords* Data Frame - Single column with "list" as header.
aaa
aaaa
aaaaaaand
aaaaand
aaaargh
aaack
aaahh
aaahhhh
aaalll
aaand
aaarse
aachen
aadityanath

Comment: What is the purpose of the angle brackets?

Comment: It's a regular expression to match whole words only, otherwise parts of words are replaced.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following vectorized approach:

```
# create a string of stopwords wrapped in `\\<` and `\\>`
x <- paste(paste0("\\<", stopwords$list, "\\>"), collapse = "|")
# use x to replace the words using gsub
corpus$text <- gsub(x, "", corpus$text)
```

(Not tested in absence of reproducible example)

To illustrate how the paste and paste0 work:

```
> ( stopwords <- letters[1:5] )
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

paste(paste0("\\<", stopwords, "\\>"), collapse = "|")
#[1] "\\<a\\>|\\<b\\>|\\<c\\>|\\<d\\>|\\<e\\>"
```

Using this in the `gsub` will replace any of the | separated stopwords with "" without looping. Essentially, it creates a single string containing all the stopwords, each wrapped into `\\<` and `\\>` because they are separated by a logical OR (which is `|` in R).

Comment: I get this error: Error in gsub(paste(paste0("\\<", stopwords$list, "\\>"), collapse = "|"),  : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634

Comment: @RUser, what if you only run `x <- paste(paste0("\\<", stopwords$list, "\\>"), collapse = "|")` - does that work? Your problem is not reproducible so it's not easy to help.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thanks! It works and gives me a char vector of all the words as above. e.g. [1] "\\<aa\\>|\\<aaa\\>|\\<aaaa\\>|\\<aaaaaaand\\>|\\<aaaaand\\>|\\<aaaargh\\>|\\<aaack\\>|\\<aaahh\\>|\\<aaahhhh\\>|\\<aaalll\\>|\\<aaand\\>|\\<aaarse\\>|\\<aachen\\>"

Comment: And after saving that to `x`, when you do `corpus$text <- gsub(paste(x, "", corpus$text)` you get an error? If yes, please provide a sample of your data.

Comment: I do get this error: Error in gsub(paste(x, "", corpus$text)) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default. I will add some sample data in the question.

Comment: There's a syntax error. Run `corpus$text <- gsub(x, "", corpus$text)`

Comment: This error again: Error in gsub(x, "", corpus$text) : 
  assertion 'tree->num_tags == num_tags' failed in executing regexp: file 'tre-compile.c', line 634. Is it not becuase it is too big? Remember I said 37,000 stopwords.

Comment: I can't help you any further than this, I fear.

Comment: Thanks for trying, I suspect the apply method will work in the end, just don't know the syntax. I tested now, if I just use 10 stopwords, it works, so it is a size thing!